# jquery validation not firing on dynamically added form fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, tooltipster

jsfiddle to show:
http://jsfiddle.net/2DUX2/277/

I'm trying to use jquery validate with tooltipster. It works until I try to add more items and then it tries to go to the form action instead of validating the new fields. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
$('#RMAForm input[type="text"], select').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    onlyOne: false,
    position: 'right'
});

// initialize validate plugin on the form
$("#RMAForm").validate({
    // any other options & rules,
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var lastError = $(element).data('lastError'),
            newError = $(error).text();

        $(element).data('lastError', newError);

        if(newError !== '' && newError !== lastError){
            $(element).tooltipster('content', newError);
            $(element).tooltipster('show');
        }
    },
    success: function (label, element) {
        $(element).tooltipster('hide');
    }
});
```

I'm using the required class on the form elements

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would have said that you failed to declare the rules on the dynamically created elements.  However, since you've declared rules via inline attributes, that part is working fine.  A form that bypasses validation means that validation is being broken (this situation is not caused by failing to declare rules on dynamic elements).

In your case, the `.validate()` method is being broken by ToolTipster, as verified by the console error.

> Error: You called Tooltipster's "content" method on an unitialized element

This means that you must also call the `.tooltipster` method *after* creating the new elements.  I simply copied the following code into your `click` handler function and placed it after the new elements are created.

```
$("#AddOne").click(function () {

    // your code that creates new form elements.

    // attach ToolTipster to new elements here...

    $('#RMAForm input, select').tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom',
        onlyOne: false,
        position: 'right'
    });

    ....
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2DUX2/278/**

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added elements, you will have to use delegate function. 
Here is more about it: [jquery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: You cannot add jQuery Validate rules to dynamically created fields in this fashion.  However, it's a moot point as the OP's `.validate()` method is being broken by ToolTipster as per the console error.  Finally, answers should be self-contained and specifically solve the OP's problem, not simply provide generic guidelines.